# How to avoid recreate fragment by FragmentManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I am having an activity with TabLayout and two fragments representing a tab content.
I manage current state of the opened tab manually in OnCreate method of my activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        //initialize or restore opened tab, after activity first started or recreated
        int tabIndex = savedInstanceState == null ? 0 : savedInstanceState.getInt("tabIndex");
        Fragment f;
        switch (tabIndex) {
            case 0:
                f = new SignInFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                f = new SignUpFragment();
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        //sync tab indicator
        tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(tabIndex));
        //set opened fragment
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.tabContent, f)
                .commit();

        //add listener to handle tab switching
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Fragment tabFragment;
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        tabFragment = new SignInFragment();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tabFragment = new SignUpFragment();
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(com.google.android.material.R.anim.abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom, com.google.android.material.R.anim.abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom)
                        .replace(R.id.tabContent, tabFragment)
                        .commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tabIndex", tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).getPosition());
    }
}
```

It is just simple sample. My real code writen in C# and have some other logic to store and manage state between activity restarts.

The problem in when configuration changes (e.g. switch orientation):

1. Opened fragment destroyed
2. Activity destroyed
3. Activity restarted
4. In onCreate method, when called super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) fragment manager recreate  fragment (destroyed in step 1) using default(parametrless) constructor.
5. My code in onCreate method restore destroyed fragment. So, fragment recreated by fragment manager destroyed and replaced to my fragment created in this step.

**How to avoid this behavior?** I'm don't needs in fragment restored by fragment manager. Also I'm don't needs in default constructor of my fragments (I have some custom ViewModel injected to fragment via constructor from hosted activity)

Put null to super.onCreate()? I think it is not good solution...

P.S. I know about ViewPager and ViewPager2 to manage tabs of TabLayout. ViewPager is deprecated. And with ViewPager2 I have strange bug: first tab (at 0 index) works fine, but in second tab I can not to focus on any input (click on input and focus immaediately lost, don't know why).

Answer (score -1):

Use global variables for fragments first create your fragments then replace them whenever you want for example :

```
private Fragment signInFragment = new SignInFragment();
private Fragment signUpFragment = new SignUpFragment();
int tabIndex = savedInstanceState == null ? 0 : 
savedInstanceState.getInt("tabIndex");
    Fragment f;
    switch (tabIndex) {
        case 0:
            f = signInFragment
            break;
        case 1:
            f = signUpFragment
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

Comment: Why? I think you don't understand the problem. I know how to store instance of fragments between tab switching. it's not a problem. The problem is in when configuration changes (e.g. orientation change) the fragment manager of hosted activity stores the type (not instance) of opened fragment. And when activity will be recreated, fm will be trying to recreate stored fragment automatically (using default fragment constructor) when super.onCreate() called. I want to avoid this, because I recreate my framents manually and use non default constructor.

Comment: Your problem is a bit confusing. I suggest using viewModel and savedInstanceState in them. So you can store all your settings or whatever you want in your viewModel. Also you can use the navigation component it is easier and solves your problem for sure.

Comment: Yes, I can. Even if I rewrite my code to use only default constructor in my fragments, it's not solving the problem. Fragment is recreates twice. The first fragment recreates automatically by FragmentManager when base/parent super.onCreate of activity is calling, The second fragment recreates by my code when I initialize tab switching logic. I found only one way to avoid this behavior - put null to super.onCreate call. That is not a problem of TabLayout. That is a problem of any fragments attached to activity - fragment manager automatically saves/restores fragments when activity restarts.

Comment: Another good and handy approach would be clearing fragment back stack after restarting activity or whenever fragment is recreating.

Comment: This won't work. You always need to use the FragmentManager to start adding, replacing or removing fragments.

Comment: I know you should have use fragmentManager that I didn't write it so you should take care yourself. See the actual code of question